# Checkbox on selected contain multiple values

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a input type radio with it's value.

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="radio1" value="someValue" />
```

My question is...is there anywhere where I can have more than 1 value per radio button?

So, if the use selects Radio1 ... is passes: SomeValue and SomeOtherValue too?

Comment: Why not put the value as `someValue,someOtherValue`; or better yet simply put the logic in the backend - `if isSelected[myRadio] value=someValue,someOtherValue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use html 5 you can use the [data](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) parameter

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="radio1" value="someValue" data-somevalue="somevalue" />
```